# Call function in script to php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Anyone know how to call `goBack()` in php?

It keep telling me:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function goBack()

and I don't know why..

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
include "session_user.php";
?>
    <script>
        function goBack(){
            alert();
            window.history.go(-1);
        }

    </script>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['d'])):

         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM bom_equipment WHERE bom_eqp_id=?");
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);

         $id = $_GET['d'];

         if($stmt->execute()):
             goBack();
         else:
              echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
         endif;
    endif;
    ?>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't call a Javascript function from PHP like that. Javascript isn't read until it's already been sent to the client's browser.

Comment: Your `goBack()` function is a JavaScript function. As far as the PHP is concerned the whole `<script>` element is just a block of text that it doesn't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: so, is there any suggestion to make it right? im only want to make it go previous page, but i dont want use location

Comment: @ChristianAnthony Calling goBack on the server side doesn't make sense. If you want the client to go back a page, you need to call the function on the client side. Read the suggested duplicate.

Comment: You can redirect to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call javascript function from php. It has lot of ways

Change your code to follows,

**Method 1**

```
<?php
include "config.php";
include "session_user.php";
?>
    <script>
        function goBack(){
            alert();
            window.history.go(-1);
        }

    </script>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['d'])):

         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM bom_equipment WHERE bom_eqp_id=?");
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);

         $id = $_GET['d'];

         if($stmt->execute()):
           echo "<script>goBack();</script>";
         else:
              echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
         endif;
    endif;
    ?>
```

**Method 2**

```
<?php
include "config.php";
include "session_user.php";

    if(isset($_GET['d'])):

         $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM bom_equipment WHERE bom_eqp_id=?");
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);

         $id = $_GET['d'];

         if($stmt->execute()):
            echo "<script>histort.back()</script>";
         else:
              echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
         endif;
    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: @ChristianAnthony Note that neither of these ways "call javascript function from php". These just produce a call to `goBack` that will be run on the client side.